# Use data of docker container inside another

Tags: python, docker, containers, dockerfile, docker-volume

A primary task is to exec into a docker container and tail log files.
This is being done inside python project where:

```
docker exec container_to_analyse tail -f /var/log...xy.log
```

was executed and stdout was passed to parsing and doing some metrics.

Works perfectly fine until i try to set my project into a docker container.

Now I can't exec into desired container and i haven't found a way to access container_to_analyse data and use it inside metric container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /metrics_docker
COPY ./* /metrics_docker/ 
WORKDIR /metrics_docker
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python" , "./data_pusher.py"]
```

My question is, how to expose container_to_analyse logs which reside inside /var/log... file to my metrics container so it can use it.

Comment: launch it using  `docker run -v my_dir_on_host:/var/log/xy.log...`?

Comment: what about mount the log file from `container_to_analyse` to host and mount it somewhere inside `metrics_container`?

Comment: can you add the `run` command for both containers? (or compose file) I'll try to help..

Comment: @user2915097 
It just makes empty directory which is unreadable (cannot follow end of this type of file; giving up on this name)

Comment: @ItayB          
container_to_analyse

    `docker run --privileged --cap-add=MKNOD --cap-add SYS_ADMIN      --shm-size 1GB --device /dev/fuse -d --restart=always -p 8081:8081 -p 11112:11112 -p 11113:11113 --link {postgres_container}--volumes-from vdata --name {image}`   container_to_metrics  `docker run rtt_container`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--volumes-from` option (like `--volumes-from container_to_analyse`) and declare /var/log/whatever a VOLUME in the Dockerfile.  Then you can access /var/log/whatever in the metrics_container.

Comment: So simple, but I missed it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of one approach on how share files:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app_writer:
    image: ubuntu
    command: sh -c "while true; do date | tee -a /var/log/shared/app.log; sleep 1; done"
    volumes:
      - ./shared/:/var/log/shared/
  app_reader:
    image: ubuntu
    command: sh -c "tail -F /var/log/shared/app.log"
    volumes:
      - ./shared/:/var/log/shared/
```

Run `docker-compose up`:

```
app_reader_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:12 UTC 2017
app_writer_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:12 UTC 2017
app_writer_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:13 UTC 2017
app_reader_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:13 UTC 2017
app_writer_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:14 UTC 2017
app_reader_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:14 UTC 2017
app_writer_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:15 UTC 2017
app_reader_1  | Thu May 18 21:35:15 UTC 2017
```

I prefer this approach over [Dockerfile VOLUME](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/).

The same but without docker-compose:

```
mkdir shared/
docker run -v ${PWD}/shared/:/var/log/shared/ -t -d ubuntu sh -c "while true; do date | tee -a /var/log/shared/app.log; sleep 1; done"
docker run -v ${PWD}/shared/:/var/log/shared/ -t ubuntu sh -c "tail -F /var/log/shared/app.log"
```

Comment: this what I suggested too, but @RicardoBranco gave an interesting solution which I didn't know before.. `--volumes-from`

Comment: That's nice! But consider [this](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/)

Comment: You can also use named volumes in Docker Compose (and even `volumes_from`).  I would add `container_name` to each service above to avoid the `_1` suffixes.
More details in: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference